# An Electric Potential Glued to a Cube-Shaped Insulator to Replicate a Point Charge: Charge Distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

I have been going back over this problem with a friend for the better part of a day:

A potential is glued to a cube-shaped insulator so that outside of the insulator the field is the same as a point particle. How can we calculate the surface charge distribution and the volume charge distribution?

Comment: This question is related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105394/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

$\def\ph{\varphi}\def\vr{\vec{r}}\def\eps{\varepsilon}\def\rmr{{\rm r}}\def\pd{\partial}\def\l{\left}\def\r{\right}\def\ltag#1{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}\def\div{\operatorname{div}}\def\grad{\operatorname{grad}}\def\nR{{\mathbb{R}}}$
You do not need a combination of a surface charge and a volume charge to re-produce a point-charge field outside a cube.

The surface-charge distribution is uniquely determined if you just use that for your purpose. The construction of this surface charge distribution is described in the first part of this answer.

If you just use a volume charge distribution this is not uniquely determined. An example for that case is given in the second part of the answer.

### Surface charge distribution

Let $V$ be the the open interior of the cube containing the origin. For points $\vr$ outside the quader we set the potential $\ph(\vr)$ equal to the potential
$$
\ph_Q(\vr) =\frac Q{4\pi\eps_0|r|}
$$
of a point charge $Q$ at the origin.
This gives you also the boundary condition
$$
\ph(\vr) = \ph_Q(\vr)\text{ for }\vr\in\partial V
$$
for the potential inside the quader. Solve the Dirichlet boundary value problem with the Laplacian equation $\Delta\ph(\vr)=0$ and with this boundary condition for the potential $\ph(r)$ at points $\vr\in V$ inside of the quader.

Let $\partial^+_\nu\ph$ and $\partial^-_\nu\ph$ be the limits of the outer normal derivatives of $\ph$ on $\partial V$ from the outside and the inside of $V$, respectively. The surface charge will be $\sigma(\vr) = -\eps_0(\partial^+_\nu\ph-\eps_{\rm r}\partial^-_\nu\ph)$. Why? Try to explain this with an integral over the surface of a small volume sitting on the surface.

Here we assume that the insulator has a homogeneous and isotropic relative permittivity $\eps_\rmr$.

---

The following picture shows a section of the solution for the Dirichlet problem in the cube $[-1,1]^3$. Only the part $\bigcup_{z\in[-1,0]}[0,-z]^2\times\{z\}$ of the cube has been modelled that generates the full cube through a sequence of reflections. Natural boundary conditions $\partial_\nu \ph=0$ were used at the symmetry planes. The Dirichtlet boundary condition at $z=-1$ is
$$\ph(x,y,z) = \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}.$$

[image: potential inside the cube]

The domain has been modelled with [gmsh](http://www.geuz.org/gmsh/) and solution is computed with [getdp](http://www.geuz.org/getdp).

The limit of the outer normal derivative of $\ph$ from the outside at the boundary $z=-1$ is
\begin{align}
\pd^+_\nu \ph(x,y,-1) &= -\pd_z \ph(x,y,-1) = \l.\frac{z}{\l(x^2+y^2+z^2\r)^{3/2}}\r|_{z=-1}\\
\ltag{derPotOutside}
&=\frac{-1}{\l(x^2+y^2+1^2\r)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
The following picture shows the field $\sigma:=-(\pd^+_\nu\ph-\pd^-_\nu\ph)$ in the boundary area $[0,1]^2\times\{-1\}$. Thereby, $\pd^+_\nu\ph$ is given by \eqref{derPotOutside} and $\pd^-_\nu\ph$ results from the numerical solution of the boundary value problem. Note, that this corresponds to a normalized solution of the original problem with $\eps_\rmr=1$.

[image: sigma]

One can check the numerical result $\sigma$ with the integral $\int_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2} \sigma(x,y,-1) dA$ which must give $\frac\pi6$. This works within the bounds of numerical precision.

For reproduction of the results I link here the [geometry definition](http://www.tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/Gmsh/quadSur4Pt.geo) and the [problem definition](http://www.tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/Gmsh/quadSur4Pt.pro) for the FEM solver.

---

The normal component of the field strength is discontinuous at the charged surface but the potential is continuous.

This can be demonstrated with a uniformly charged circular disk in the (x,y)-plane with center at the origin and radius $R$. We denote the charge density with $\sigma$. The complement of the disk is free space with permitivity $\eps_0$. For the demonstration we calculate the potential on the z-axis:
\begin{align}
\ph(z) &= \frac\sigma{4\pi\eps_0}\int_{r=0}^R \frac{ 2\pi r dr}{\sqrt{r^2 + z^2}}\\
&=\frac\sigma{2\eps_0} \left[\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\right]_{r=0}^R\\
&=\frac\sigma{2\eps_0} \left(\sqrt{R^2+z^2}-|z|\right)
\end{align}
The potential can be continuously extended at $z=0$ with the value
\begin{align}
\ph(0) = \frac {\sigma R}{2\eps_0}.
\end{align}

### Volume charge distribution

The volume charge distribution is not uniquely determined. For an instance if you have $\eps_\rmr=1$ you can put a ball with uniform volume charge into the cube. That is
$$
\rho(\vr) = \begin{cases}
\frac{Q}{\frac34\pi R^3}&\text{ for }|\vr|<R\\
0&\text{ else}
\end{cases}
$$ 
with $R$ sufficiently small such that the ball fits into the cube.

Another possible space charge distribution is
\begin{align}
\rho(\vr) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\frac87 Q}{\frac34\pi R^3}&\text{ for } \frac12 R<|\vr|<R,\\
0&\text{ else.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

If the insulator is a quader with constant permitivity $\eps_\rmr\neq1$ then you have given:

1. the potential $\ph$ on the boundary $\partial V$ of the quader by the outer potential field $\ph^+(\vr)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\eps_0|\vr|}$ of the point charge
2. the normal derivative $\partial^-_\nu\ph$ at the boundary of the quader through the normal component of the charge displacement density $$\partial^-_\nu\ph(\vr) = \frac1{\eps_\rmr}\partial^+_\nu\ph(\vr).$$

The taks is now to find an at least two times differentiable scalar function $\ph:V\rightarrow\nR$ interpolating the required potential and the required normal derivative at $\partial V$. The Volume charge density can then be calculated by
$$
\rho(\vr) = -\eps_\rmr\eps_0 \Delta \ph(\vr).
$$

---

The actual problem for varying $\eps_r$ is
\begin{align}
\div\l(\eps(\vr) \grad\ph(\vr)\r) = -\rho.
\end{align}
In your case $\eps(\vr)$ is even discontinous such that you need the weak form of $\eps(\vr)$ and you end up with the problem:
\begin{align}
\int_{\nR^3} (\grad\delta\ph(\vr))\eps(\vr)\grad\ph(\vr) d V = \int_{\nR^3} \delta\ph(\vr)\rho(\vr) dV
\end{align}
for all test functions $\delta\ph$. This can be solved numerically.

I do not know if there are known Green functions for that problem.

Comment: @walczyk: Some info was missing in the answer (e.g., the exact meanding of $\partial^+_\nu$ and $\partial^-_\nu$. I added that. Hope, now it is comprehensible.

Comment: How do we know the potential inside the cube? It's not uniquely determined correct?

Comment: Also will the inner side of the normal derivative be the electric field, but with a new epsilon value?

Comment: I added an example that demonstrates that the potential keeps continuous across a surface charge. It is not a proof but it could be extended to one. The potential is uniquely determined with appropriate boundary conditions at infinity for the problem with the surface charge. One requires that the absolute value of the potential decays like $1/|\vec r|$ sufficiently far from the origin. I have also added a relative permittivity for the insulator.

Comment: @walczyk: I have added an example.

Comment: Where does eps_r come into play here? When you calculated dV/dz, don't we subtract the outside by the inside? so that there's a (1-e_r) or something factor, if we integrate over the side, you say we should get a pi/6 ? Also your plot, I have a hard time following it, I thought the surface must replicate a point charge, so it would be stronger at the center and weak at the edges, azimuthal symmetry.

Comment: If I follow your example the surface charge density at the z=-1 side should be (note da should be -dxdy*k^hat, pointing out of the box) $\frac{q*\epsilon_0}{4*Pi*\epsilon_0*(x^2+y^2+1)} - \frac{q*\epsilon_0}{4*Pi*\epsilon_r*(x^2+y^2+1)}$ Is that what you're suggesting is the surface charge density? If we integrate this over one side, and multiply by 6, do you think it should equal q? would the difference in be due to the fact that we have to account for the volume charge as well? I am curious how you would solve this completely.

Comment: edit i think i should have ^3/2 there , so we have z/r^3 for dV/dn

Comment: Also you say " Solve the Dirichlet boundary value problem with the Laplacian equation" but I thought this would be Poisson Equation because there is a volume charge...

Comment: @walczyk: 1) I added an intro telling that you can use a surface charge **or** a volume charge. 2) $\eps_\rmr$ is regarded in the general description. I set $\eps_\rmr=1$ in the numerical example. 3) You got the surface charge in the example wrong. The second term results from the numerical solution of the Dirichlet problem. 4) No, we must multiply the numerical integral by 24 since we only have $\frac14$ of one side of the cube. 5) The numerical example is for surface charge only. Therefore, only the Laplacian equation is to be solved. 6) I also added a 2nd example for volume charge.

Comment: I see, I'm afraid I still have two standing questions. I get an answer $\pd^+_\nu \ph(x,y,-1) = \frac{-1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}}$ when I take the derivative of the potential wrt z. Also you said that for the interior side of the boundary, I am supposed to use a numerical solution. How would I go about getting this numerical solution?

Comment: If I used a Green's Function, what would be the rho distribution that I'd use for it?

Comment: I think this link explains the process clearly, but what is our justification for solving laplace's equation inside the insulator, as opposed to poisson's equation?

Comment: Oops, this link:  http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter5/5.10.html

I think I understand, regarding my second question, of where to go next. Expanding in cos*cos*cosh basically.

Comment: @walczyk: Thank to point out the missing exponent $3/2$. That was just a typo. The exponent in the [problem definition file](http://www.tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/Gmsh/quadSur4Pt.pro) is right. To get the outer normal you must multiply $\pd_z^+\ph$ with -1 because it is the bottom surface. In the numerical example we have surface charge only. Therefore, Laplacian instead of Poisson (that was point (5)). The construction of a $\rho$ distributions is very simple (see answer).

Comment: I think I've almost done it completely right, except and extra 1/(4*Pi) is needed to get the right answer. I must have forget it somewhere...

Comment: A final answer of around 4*Pi/6 . . . But I already have 1/4Pi in the terms I was evaluating, unlike you where you added them in later..

Comment: @walczyk Sorry, maybe I have confused you. The example is an example, nothing more. I just started from the potential. Maybe, this is the source of confusion. You can also calculate a point charge for the potential. That would be $4\pi\eps_0$ for that case. In numerics for pde you sometimes work with normalized quantities because of these already tell you all you need.

Comment: I think I've solved it with the right boundary conditions, if we are centered, x,y goes from -1/2 to +1/2, and the wavenumbers for our series solution are something like 2*pi*m. When I try for a solution like this, I get the exact answer, of q. The interior dV/dn vanishes when integrated over x and y. I guess that's okay? I just expected it to not give me the exact answer, to all orders. This has to do with the 2, in 2*pi*m.

Comment: @walczyk I've added an approach to find an appropriate charge density $\rho$ inside the cube.

Comment: Right after you said "If the insulator is a quader with constant permitivity \eps\rmr≠1 then you have given:" you state the normal derivative at the surface. If I should take the difference between the outside and inside surfaces, integrated over each side, should i get Q for a total? does that mean the charge on the outside should be different than Q, basically Q' - Q'/e_r = Q ?

Comment: @walczyk No, that condition ensures that the charge integrals on both sides of the surface are equal. The charge displacement density times the surface normal is $\eps_\rmr\eps_0\pd^-_\nu\ph=\eps_0\pd^+_\nu\ph$. But, I wrote down a boundary condition for $\ph^-$ (potential inside the cube), therefore the form $\pd^-_\nu\ph^-=\frac1{\eps_\rmr}\pd^+_\nu\ph^+$. Note, that it is actually one potential $\ph$. But, I added $\pm$ for clarity here.