# Electric field intensity of spherical shell (with cut out cap)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

Consider a charged spherical shell of radius $R$ and surface charge density $\sigma$. Choose a point on the surface of the shell and cut a spherical cap of radius $a \ll R$. What is the electric field intensity in the middle of the hole?

This was made up intended as a relatively easy problem to solve, it turns out however it is probably not, as every edition of the textbook shows a different answer and professors at our physics department can't agree upon one. What do you think?

My attempt: First I calculated the intensity on the axis of a disc and integrated over the disc elements: $\vec E = \int_0^{2R-{a^2 \over 2R -1}} {\sigma \over 2\epsilon} ({ \sqrt{2Rh} - |h| })dh$. This, using the fact that $a \ll R^2$ evaluates to ${\sigma R^2 \over 3\epsilon} $, which is wrong.

Comment: Well, first, what do you think? We typically don't solve textbook style problems from scratch here. If you have an attempted solution we're happy to comment on why we think it's correct or incorrect. Please read the homework policy http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info (which applies to homework-like questions as well as actual homework).

Comment: @Kyle: Oh, I'm sorry. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ph{\varphi}\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}\def\eps{\varepsilon}\def\l{\left}\def\r{\right}$
The radially symmetric charge displacement density field of homogeneous surface charge on a sphere with middle point at the origin has only a r-component
\begin{align}
  D_r(r) &=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{4\pi R^2\sigma}{4\pi r^2} &\text{ for } r>0,\\
    0 &\text{ for } r<0.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
On the positive z-axis this can be written as
\begin{align}
  D_r(z) &= \frac{\sigma R^2}{2 r^2}(1+\sign(z-R))
\end{align}

The field of a uniformly charged disk of radius $a$ at $z=R$ with
normal in z-direction and with surface charge $-\sigma$ is
\begin{align}
  D_z(z) &= \frac{-\sigma}2\l(\sign(z-R)-\frac{z-R}{\sqrt{a^2+(z-R)^2}}\r).
\end{align}
This results from the derivative of the potential for this problem which I already described in [another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105427/an-electric-potential-glued-to-a-cubic-insulator-to-replicate-a-point-charge-ch/105486#105486). For small $a$ we hope to approximate the hole by such a disk with opposite $\sigma$ to the surface charge of the sphere. This should give a first order approximation in the order of $a/R$.

Superposition of the fields gives
\begin{align}
  D_z(z) = \frac{\sigma}2\l(\frac{R^2}{z^2}-1\r)\sign(z-R)+\frac{\sigma R^2}{2z^2}+\frac{\sigma(z-R)}{2\sqrt{a^2+(z-R)^2}}
\end{align}
and at $z=R$ this gives $D_z(z) = \frac{\sigma}2$ the corresponding E-field is $E_z=\frac\sigma{2\eps_0}$.

Let us evaluate $D_z\l(\sqrt{R^2-a^2}\r)$ as [mirgee](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/43408/mirgee) suggested. Note, that $\sign(z-R)=-1$ in that case.
\begin{align}
 D_z\l(\sqrt{R^2-a^2}\r)&\approx D_z\l(R-\frac{a^2}{2R}\r)\\
&=\frac{\sigma}2+\frac{\sigma\l(-\frac{a^2}{2R}\r)}{2\sqrt{a^2+\l(\frac{a^2}{2R}\r)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\sigma}2+\frac{\sigma\l(-\frac{a^2}{2R}\r)}{2a\sqrt{1+\l(\frac a{2R}\r)^2}}\\
&\approx\frac{\sigma}2\l(1-\frac{a}{2R}\r)
\end{align}

---

To take 2nd order info for the disk into account one assumes that the charged disk is curved. The z-coordinate of the disk $z_\sigma$ in dependence of the radial position $\rho$ from the axis is
$$
z_\sigma \approx R\cos\l(\frac \rho R\r) \approx R\l(1-\frac12\l(\frac\rho R\r)^2\r)
$$
The potential on the axis becomes
\begin{align}
\ph(z) &= \frac{\sigma}{4\pi\eps_0} \int_{\rho=0}^a \frac{2\pi\sqrt{1+\l(\frac{\rho}R\r)^2}\rho d\rho}{\sqrt{(z-z_\sigma)^2 + \rho^2}}
\end{align}

Now it is time-out for me. I have to go to work.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. The answer reads ${\sigma \over 2\epsilon}(1 - {a \over R})$, however. What approximations do you think were made? I guess they supposed that the field in the sphere is zero.

Comment: @mirgee Sorry for the typo with $\eps_0$. Usually one calculates the product $D=\eps_0 E$ and here we had the other way around... I fixed this. The two answers differ only in the order of $a/R$. The constant part is the same. That means in the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ they are the same. The point where I did make an approximation is that I neglected the curvature of the sphere. Maybe, one could take this into account as a Taylor series approximation.

Comment: So how to take the curvature into account? And also, why are you evaluating $D_z(z)$ at $z=R$ and not $R-{a^2 \over 2R -1}$?

Comment: @mirgee Do you mean $z=\sqrt{R^2-a^2}\approx R \l(1-\frac12\l(\frac aR\r)^2\r)=R-\frac{a^2}{2R}$? These are changes in the order of $(a/R)^2\rightarrow0$ and can be neglected(?). Furthermore it depends on how one interprets "middle of the hole". As a hole of the sphere one could look on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: @mirgee With $z=R-\frac{a^2}{2R}$ I get $\frac{\sigma}{2\eps_0}\l(1-\frac a{2R}\r)$. Maybe, it is too late here and I made some mistake...

Comment: Added the functional determinant for the 2nd order representation of the integral. We have to integrate along $\rho \mapsto (\rho,z_\sigma)=\l(\rho,R\cos(\rho/R)\r)$. That gives $|d\vec r| = \sqrt{1+\l(-R\sin(\rho/R)/R\r)^2}d\rho\approx\sqrt{1+\l(\rho/R\r)^2}d\rho$. Therefore, I had to delete the stuff for the 2nd order D-field:-(.